# How to add more lines in a Xamarin Pin

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add more lines in my Xamarin application.
I am using Xamarin maps to add pins to the map. I thought that Xamarin pin renders differently from Google maps markers so I tried writing a paragraph and it seems they are limited to 1 line. I know for sure that on Google maps marker you need to make a custom snippet but is this the same case for Xamarin? I don't want a full custom one just more lines to write. Is there any customisation without making a custom renderer for xamarin maps? I couldn't find any website about this.
Thanks alot

Comment: you need to write a custom pin

Comment: Oh so that's how you do it . Oh okay. Thanks